# Unexpected chart points in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm getting unexpected plot-points in d3.js. I start with:

```
var lineData = [13, 16, 2];
```

Then massage it into:

```
[{x: 0, y: 24.375},
{x: 55, y: 30},
{x: 110, y: 3.75}]
```

But for some reason, the chart that I'm creating doesn't look like it matches this data at all.  I'm probably missing something simple, but I can't put my finger on it. Any help is appreciated.

Also, I won't be surprised if there are better "d3 ways" to massage the data as I intend to. Bonus points if you can point out how the code could be improved ;)

I've created a JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/matrym/qbDhq/1/

Comment: Your points are plotted "correctly". Probably a couple of things are throwing you off: 1) The origin is at the top-left, not bottom right, so all your Y values are being plotted relative to the top of the `<path>`, not the bottom as one typically expects. 2) The svg is not at the top of its containing div, so an additional offset is introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in SVG, y coordinates are counted from the top, not the bottom. So 0 is the top. You want to return `chartHeight - d.y` in your line function.

As for other improvements, you can use a scale to compute the y values directly from the data. The D3 way would be to bind the data to the appended `path` element and then simply pass in the line function instead of calling it explicitly.

All of this and a few smaller things [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qbDhq/2/).